# PowerPoint addin close event

Tags: powerpoint, office-js

I would like to log a user out when they close a power point content addin. Preferably, when the user closes the addin, they are prompted to wait a few moments to be logged out. Is there an onclose event available to use? The windows onclose and beforeunload events do not seem to give enough time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that there is no API at this time for handling the event of the add-in closing. It is an interesting idea. Consider proposing this on [Office Developer Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).